# qtcreator ui and dark theme unreadable

Tags: qt, qt-creator, pyside, qt-designer

I am running qtcreator on gnome with Adwaita-dark.
When designing the gui, everything looks fine (left), but when I run it, the text is only visible when hovering over it (right).

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: are you sure about QWidget stylesheet.when you set stylesheet to a widget at code space (not to design mode) ,can not see the stylesheet effect at design mode and just must run them .

Answer (score 0):

On the designer window, click on the **inherit** button, under `Property->QWidget->Palete`
[image]